# Optimizing Redis hash structure for a counter app

Tags: redis

I have a counter app with a Redis hash structure like so:

```
hset id:123 a1 3 a2 5 a3 17 a4 36 a5 8 a6 2 a7 3 a8 9 a10 23 b1 23 b2 7…
```

In any given hash id:*, I have 3 key groups:

**1-10** keys, 150 variations

```
a1...a10
b1...b10
...
```

**1-5** keys, 30 variations

```
m1...m5
n1...n5
...
```

**1-2** keys, 10 variations

```
x1...x2
y1...y2
...
```

Total # of keys in a hash: 190.

Total # of hashes: ~500.

Int values for each key in any group: 0-1,000,000, with 90% under 100,000.

Total count for each group of key variations is the same as any other:

```
i.e, Sum(a1...a10) = Sum(x1...y1)
```

Only one key:value is incremented in each key group, all key groups in a hash are updated in a MULTI/EXEC.

While this simple hash structure works, I have a couple of questions:

1. What should I set my hash-max-zipmap-entries and hash-max-zipmap-value to? 190 and 32?
2. Can anyone think of a simpler, less verbose, smaller-memory, faster alternative in Redis something like bitsets?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what issue you are trying to solve with this counter hash?

Comment: It's a straightforward  counter that keeps track of preferences within a data collection process. Think of it as a page with grouped rows of radio buttons: a1…a10, b1…b10, m1…m5, x1…x2, etc. I need to know how many clicked, say, a8 or m3 or y2 and so on, over time. It's like population count, in one sense. Every button value has to be tracked.